# In-app purchase for bulk data - iOS

Tags: ios, server, in-app-purchase, payment-gateway

I am working on an application, using this users can buy '**QRCodes**'. We already has a web site doing the same. So in the app, we load the `Webview` with product details, fetching from backend server and allow the users to buy. But, Apple has rejected the app as we are using third party Payment gateways for purchasing '**Digital Goods**'.

Now we are planning to use **IAP**. I am new to this and little confused.. I have few questions regarding integrating IAP to our app.

1. In which category QRCodes will come? (Consumable, Non-consumable, etc..)
2. Is it mandatory to add each product in IAP? (in iTunesConnect.apple.com)
3. Is there any way to load bulk data to IAP? Rather than add one by one?
4. Is there any way to connect IAP to my existing server for fetching the data directly from backend DB?

Please share your suggestions.

Comment: If you have a large amount of product and they are dynamic you can consider using generic consumable items. I think you have the same situation described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39031572/is-in-app-purchase-applicable-for-ebooks-audiobooks and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29861332/using-generic-in-app-purchase-items-for-a-dynamic-range-of-digital-products?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. So as mentioned in the given SO link, the best option is to create different price group for all price range and add the productID in the server? Or is there any alternative option as the items are dynamic at the server?

Comment: I think thats the best option. Another option might be to sell virtual coins via IAP and user can buy items buy spending them (not the best idea I would say).