# One in-app product with multiple variations

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

Can I create one in-app product for, say, some music, and then vary the exact track based on a database key?

So the user would buy a *music product* but the app keeps track of the exact data which comprises their instance?

Comment: I did not understand the question. Do mean like "buy track of the week" and the actual track differs every week?

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding you. Do you want to sell the user a credit for a music piece and the user than can decide which song it uses the credit for?

Comment: Similar. There's a database of songs created by users, so its not practical to set up an in-app product for each song. Instead, there's one in-app product  called 'A Song' and, yes, the user is deciding which song it actually is.

Comment: You can set up a consumable in-app purchase for a "music credit" and then allow the user to redeem that credit for a music product of their choice.

Comment: Great, although I'm setting it up such that the "credit" is purchased and spent at the same time. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Paulw11](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3418066/paulw11) said in his comment above, you can setup a consumable product ID that offers one or more "credits". Using the concept of credits is the only way you can dynamically allocate products to purchases without adding a product ID for each song in iTunes Connect.

Consumable products can be purchased multiple times, so allocate credit or direct the user to select the song once they buy the product. Be sure to call [finishTransaction](https://developer.apple.com/reference/storekit/skpaymentqueue/1506003-finishtransaction) to "consume" the purchase, otherwise the transaction will remain in the queue and additional purchases will be blocked.

Be warned though, consumables are not restorable; if the user deletes and re-installs the app all their songs will be lost. One way to deal with this is to keep a server-side registry of songs a user has purchased, which means you will need user management and authentication etc.

Here's [another stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29861332/using-generic-in-app-purchase-items-for-a-dynamic-range-of-digital-products?rq=1) relates to yours.